# How can I make a comma delimited list of xml values? xml version 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have searched for an answer to this with no luck.  I'm sure I have overlooked the answer somewhere. However, I am trying to print/display a subset of xml values as a comma delimited list. Here is an example of what I am trying to do;

XML Doc.

```
<vehicle>
  <car new="y">
    <yr>2012</yr>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mustang</model>
    <color>Blue</color>
  </car>
  <car new="y">
    <yr>2012</yr>
    <make>Chevy</make>
    <model>Camaro</model>
    <color>Red</color>
  </car>
  <car new="y">
    <yr>2012</yr>
    <make>Subaru</make>
    <model>Impreza</model>
    <color>White</color>
  </car>
  <car new="n">
    <yr>2000</yr>
    <make>Toyota</make>
    <model>Tacoma</model>
    <color>Silver</color>
  </car>
  <car new="n">
    <yr>1998</yr>
    <make>Dodge</make>
    <model>Durango</model>
    <color>Green</color>
  </car>
</vehicle>
```

XSL DOC..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/" >

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <h2> New Cars </h2>
      <p>
        <xsl:for-each select="vehicle/car">
        <xsl:sort select="./yr" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:if test="./@new='y'">
        <xsl:value-of select="yr" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="make" />
        <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="model" />
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, in this example I want to select all "new" cars and place them in a comma delimited list and not have a comma after the last item in the list.

I can't use `xsl:if test="position() != last()>` since the position of the "last" "new" car may not be the "last" position in the xml. I would prefer this to be done in xml version 1.0.

Any Suggestions or Ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Example output:

```
2012 Ford Mustang, 2012 Chevy Camaro, 2012 Subaru Impreza
```

Comment: @Brogrammer - He's not trying to create a CSV...he's building a `<p>` in an HTML document.

Comment: @Brogrammer: The purpose of each technology isn't to outdo the last.  It is to provide functionality that the previous technologies lacked.  Just because an old technology doesn't have a feature doesn't mean it is worthless.  You're assuming too much about what they want to *do* with the resulting csv.  This output might be for a screen representation or output to a log file, in which case it is perfectly fine to do the transform in the language designed to do the transform.

Comment: This isn't a homework assignment.  I am trying to teach myself some xml and one of the book examples is to make a comma delimited list of "all" items which is easy. But when I tried to do a similar example as posted I ran in to problems. I knew that I couldn't use the test for the last position but I had no clue how to solve it otherwise.

Comment: @DevNull hmm true sorry, My bad!

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham , I will keep that in my mind, thanks!

Comment: @Brogrammer: To be fair to your point, yes I would always pick a tech that wouldn't tie me to well known limits if it were the right tool for the job.  CSV gets nasty very quickly.  But for an export format for reports, it is good.  If your data really *doesn't* have to be anything but CSV, it is extremely easy to implement a parser (good on an embedded system where you don't get lovely things like pre-implemented XML parsers).  As you've alluded to, as soon as you struggle with fitting data in that format, I'd ditch it for JSON in a heartbeat. Now .ini - there's a mid-step we can deal without

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham, Yeah I asked because CSV might be good for places where you need try little amount of data to deal with. However nowadays very little amount of data is very rare. However I should rather solve Matt's problem instead ranting lol...But yeah I thought of sharing what I think :) but learnt something new :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:for-each select="vehicle/car[@new='y']">
```

instead of getting them all and using an if test.  Then you can use last().

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy solution for this!! Thank you for your quick answer!!